# How to define custom char type that accepts a subset of the normal charset

Tags: rust, types

I'm trying to define a custom type of char that only accepts values from `A-Z`. Right now i'm just using a plain char in my type:

```rs
struct Rotor {
    cipher: &'static str,
    notch: &'static [char],
    position: char, // Only valid values are A-Z
}
```

And here's a method that is invoked periodically on this struct

```rs
fn rotate(&mut self) {
        match self.position /* E0004 on this line */ { 
            'A'..='Y' => self.position = (self.position as u8 + 1) as char,
            'Z' => self.position = 'A',
        }
    }
```

the match statement in my rotate method is giving me compiler error `E0004: ensure that all possible cases are being handled by adding a match arm with a wildcard pattern, a match arm with multiple or-patterns as shown, or multiple match arms`

If I could have a custom char type that only had values `A-Z` possible that would eliminate this error. I've considered using the following pattern: `const CHARSET: &[u8] = b"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";` but I can't figure out how to get that to work with the struct definition

I know that if I just added a catch-all `_` arm to this match statement it wouldn't be the end of the world but I would much prefer to not have to do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rust does not support ranged integers (at least currently) and thus you cannot define your own character type and have the compiler enforce exhaustiveness with it. You have to use a wildcard. By the way, you can use the smaller and more efficient `u8` if you only need `A`-`Z`.

You can use a newtype wrapper and have the constructor enforcing the validity of the value. This will not help with `match`, but will help to prevent bugs.

Comment: Could I use ranged int's and then interpret them as chars? like `type CHARSET is range b'A'..= b'Z'`?

Comment: @BrandonPiña "Rust **does not support** ranges integers".

Comment: aww shucks. Looks like I might just have to deal with it then

Comment: _"Rust does not support ranged integers"_ => This is not _quite_ correct. Rust may not have _built-in_ support for range integers, but the language supports defining _types_ that will perform the validation.

Comment: @MatthieuM. You can say the same about any language that supports privacy. When people ask for support for ranged integers, they mean built in support IMO.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman: I disagree, Rust supports defining a _generic_ `RangedInteger<T, const MIN: i128, const MAX: i128>` type which only few languages support.