# What is the idiomatic way to achieve ranged integers in Rust?

Tags: rust, ada

In the Ada programming language, one can use the [*range constraint*](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-3-5.html) to declare that the value of a signed integer has to be within a minimum and maximum. An exception is triggered if not, for [example](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Types/range).

What is the idiomatic way to achieve this in Rust?

Comment: Related: [How to define custom char type that accepts a subset of the normal charset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72758372/how-to-define-custom-char-type-that-accepts-a-subset-of-the-normal-charset/)

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Thanks! That was helpful but didn't really solve my problem. However, this crate probably did: https://docs.rs/ranged_integers/latest/ranged_integers/

Comment: Here is an interesting discussion as well: https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/more-on-ranged-integers/8614

Comment: Note (on the Ada side) that ranges appear in many places: array bounds, `for` loops, `case` statements, ... They are involved in compile-time checks too and also in the removal of run-time checks when it is safe to do so.

Comment: Zerte's point is crucial ... this should not involve runtime checks when the check can possibly (and safely) be moved to compile time, And if an array and a loop over it share a range, it's impossible to index off the array (Heartbleed). How closely can the Rust version approach the efficiency and safety of that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, compile-time ranged types are not implemented in Rust. There is a discussion at [internals.rust-lang.org](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/more-on-ranged-integers/8614) and several open GitHub issues: [Range types for integers (or refinement types?) #671](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/671) and [Numerical Constrained Types #1621](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/1621). There is an experimental [crate ranged_integers](https://github.com/disiamylborane/ranged_integers) that prototypes ranged integers.

For a runtime implementation, you can define your type, e.g.,

```
struct RangedInt<const MIN: int, const MAX: int>(int);
```

and add checks in the operators' implementations.